# Python: read multiple text files and write corresponding csv files

Tags: python, csv, text

I can't quite find the answer to this question elsewhere, and so I am going to go ahead and post it here:

I have a Python script which will read the contents of a text file, split its contents into words, and then output a CSV file which has reduced the text to a word frequency list. (Eventually I will insert a line to drop words, but I haven't gotten that far.) What I would like to do next with this script is point it at a directory of text files and have it iterate over those files, producing a corresponding CSV file for each TXT file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import glob
import re
import csv

files = {}
for fpath in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(fpath) as f:
        words = re.split('\s+', f.read().lower())
        freq_dic = {}
        punctuation = re.compile(r'[.?!,":;]') 
    for word in words:
        word = punctuation.sub("", word)
        try:
            freq_dic[word] += 1
        except: 
            freq_dic[word] = 1
    word_list = [(val, key) for key, val in freq_dic.items()]
    sorted(word_list, reverse=True)
    with outputfile as myfileout:
        writer = csv.writer(myfileout)
        writer.writerows(sorted(word_list, reverse=True))
```

You can tell, I hope, that I am simply working "up" from the working script, but I got a little lost. I am pretty proud of the `with` loop on the file output, but I flailed trying to turn the input into a `with` loop as well.

When I run this script in a directory with 20 texts in it, I get the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-c16fff380b6f> in <module>()
     17     word_list = [(val, key) for key, val in freq_dic.items()]
     18     sorted(word_list, reverse=True)
---> 19     with outputfile as myfileout:
     20         writer = csv.writer(myfileout)
     21         writer.writerows(sorted(word_list, reverse=True))

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?  You can easily get a list of text files with `txt = [i for i in os.listdir('.') if i.endswith('.txt')]` and then apply the word frequency function to each file. Also, [`nltk`](http://nltk.org/) might interest you.  It has classes for dealing with corpora (directory of text files), easily breaks files into words, and has `FreqDist` for calculating frequencies.

Comment: Edited post to include error report -- because you can't do it in a comment. (And have it be readable.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the output file to write the frequencies.  You did that fine when reading the file, so apply the same concept when writing to a file:

```
for fpath in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    frequencies = getFrequencies(fpath)  # assume function returns list of (word, freq) pairs
    outfile = 'output.{0}'.format(fpath)  # generate a name for the output file somehow
    with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
        wtr = csv.writer(f)
        wtr.writerows(frequencies)
        f.close()
```

You can create a function from your existing code to handle the frequency calculations:

```
def getFrequencies(fpath):
    with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
        words = re.split('\s+', f.read().lower())
        freq_dic = {}
        punctuation = re.compile(r'[.?!,":;]') 
    for word in words:
        word = punctuation.sub("", word)
        try:
            freq_dic[word] += 1
        except: 
            freq_dic[word] = 1
    return [(val, key) for key, val in freq_dic.items()]
```

Also have a look at `collections.Counter` for updating the counts.

Comment: @ChristP: If I take those two pieces of code and use them together, the output is only one csv file, and I can't tell which file it has gone over: it's not the first file in the directory, and it's not the entire directory: the word counts are too low. Perhaps I took your response too literally?

Comment: I get how the defined function works: that's cool, but I don't see how the first block of code iterates through each text file to produce a cdv file for each one.

Comment: Yep, you will have to generate a new file for each input file.  I edited my response to clarify.  There are a number of ways to do this.  [`os.path.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) might interest you.